# How to hide and show 2 different prefabs?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a tower defense game in unity, and one of the features is to upgrade the units you placed. I've got the showing of the first turret prefab, but when I go to show the upgraded one, the first hides like normal, but the second one doesn't show like it should.

some code I think is relevant to this issue.

```
if (CanPlaceInfantry())
        {
            // 3
            infantry = (GameObject)
                Instantiate(infantryPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            // 4
            AudioSource audioSource = gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
            audioSource.PlayOneShot(audioSource.clip);

            gameManager.Gold -= infantry.GetComponent<InfantryData>().CurrentLevel.cost;

        } else if (CanUpgradeInfantry())
        {
            infantry.GetComponent<InfantryData>().IncreaseLevel();
            AudioSource audioSource = gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
            audioSource.PlayOneShot(audioSource.clip);
        }
    }

    private bool CanUpgradeInfantry()
    {
        if (infantry != null)
        {
            InfantryData infantryData = infantry.GetComponent<InfantryData>();
            InfantryLevel nextLevel = infantryData.GetNextLevel();
            if (nextLevel != null)
            {
                return gameManager.Gold >= nextLevel.cost;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

```
public void IncreaseLevel()
    {
        int currentLevelIndex = levels.IndexOf(currentLevel);
        if (currentLevelIndex < levels.Count - 1)
        {
            CurrentLevel = levels[currentLevelIndex + 1];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nowhere in your snippets I see where anything would get "shown" or "hidden" ... Is `CurrentLevel` a property where stuff is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Those are some of the things you could do with your old Tower to Hide it and with your new Tower to Show it.

**Instantiaing / Deleting GameObject:**

```
// Instantiating the new Tower, at transform.position
Instantiate(gameObject, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

// Deleting the old Tower
Destroy(gameObject);
```

**Activate / Deactivating GameObject:**

```
// Setting Position of new Tower
gameObject.transform.position = transform.position;
// Activating new Tower
gameObject.SetActive(true);

// Deactivatingn old Tower
gameObject.SetActive(false);
```

**Hiding / Showing GameObject:**

```
// Hiding each Render to make the GameObject invisible
foreach (Transform child in transform) {
  child.gameObject.GetComponent< Renderer >().enabled = false;
}
GetComponent< Renderer >().enabled = false;

// To make it visible again replace theese 2 lines
GetComponent< Renderer >().enabled = false;
GetComponent< Renderer >().enabled = true;
```

**Hiding / Showing GameObject(if it's really a huge object):**

```
// Hiding each Render to make the GameObject invisible
void Start() {
  recDisabler(transform);
}
 
private void recDisabler(Transform t) {
    if (t.childCount > 0) {
        foreach (Transform child in t) {
            recDisabler(child);
        }
    }
    t.gameObject.GetComponent< Renderer >().enabled = false;
}

// To make it visible again replace theese 2 lines
t.gameObject.GetComponent< Renderer >().enabled = false;
t.gameObject.GetComponent< Renderer >().enabled = true;
```